# try catch continue execution on exception

Tags: java, exception

This question was asked to me on an interview. In the below snippet the exception occur in the third line of the try block. The question was how to make the 4th line execute. The third line should be in the catch block itself. They gave me an hint 'using throw and throws'.

```
    public void testCase() throws NullPointerException{
        try{
            System.out.println("Start");
            String out = null;
            out.toString();
            System.out.println("Stop");

        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }
    }
```

Can any one help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the fourth line in a `finally` block ?

Comment: You mean the exception is thrown in the third line `out.toString();` How can exception be thrown from an assignment statement.

Comment: You want the third line executed? `out.toString()`? Out isn't declared previously, so what ideally should it be returning anyway? And you do nothing with the result, so why? My guess is you want the FOURTH line executed?

Comment: Your statement "the exception occur in the 2nd line of the try block" is false. The third line will throw an NPE. The 3rd line being in a catch block itself will not change anything.

Comment: What changes are allowed? I mean, I can just use put "" instead of null, otherwise. So what are allowed changes?

Comment: sorry i am correcting the question.

Comment: There are lots of ways this could be made to work. I think the point of the question is to make sure you are familiar with Java's exception paradigm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the exception happens on the **third** line of the try block - at the `out.toString()`, not the 2nd line.

And I am assuming you want the fourth line to execute (ie. printing stop)

There are different ways to make the next line (printing stop) to execute, if you want to simply make the Stop is printed:

```
 public static void testCase() throws NullPointerException{
        try{
            System.out.println("Start");
            String out = null;
            out.toString();
            System.out.println("Stop");

        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("Stop");
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }
    }
```

or given the hint that

> the third line should be in the catch block itself

```
 public static void testCase() throws NullPointerException{
        try{
            System.out.println("Start");
            String out = null;
            Exception e = null;

            try
            {
                out.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                e = ex;
            }
            System.out.println("Stop");

            if(e != null)
                throw e;

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }
    }
```

There are other ways to do this, eg. finally block, etc. But with the limited amount of information given and with the goal of making it work - the above should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
public void testCase() throws NullPointerException{
        try{
            System.out.println("Start");
            String out = null;
            out.toString();
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("Exception");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Stop");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thorny snippet, the question was :

- what's happen when you crash an internal address, here
  `out` output, is replaced with `String` but it is `null`,
  or
- is it possible to print a `null String`, with a snippet around to focuse your attention.

you can  rewrite the line :  **`("" + out).toString();`** to pass to forth one.

'As is' it is not a technical interview, unless  you have to push a second question about you have to do with the third line.

Test was : what the candidate does when he not see all parts of a problem, or when a problem is nested, is it able to ask help to understand the real problem.

*EDIT after comment*

Unless you comment the line, you have to capture the corrupted code :

```
try {
    // Corrupted code to avoid 
    String out = null;
    out.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Careful (and professionnal) signal
    System.out.println("out.toString() : code to repair.");
} 
System.out.println("Stop"); // will appear to console
```

Comment: Let me quote you the question exactly it was put to me."If there are 15 line of code inside a try-catch block and the exception occures at the fifth line. and because of some personal reason i want to execute the other lines" and then they hinted of "Using throw and throws". Any suggestion.